# Passing Varargin into fprintf

Tags: matlab, variadic-functions, printf

Is there a way to pass the inputs in `varargin` to `fprintf` within a loop?

For example if you have something like:

```
    function = func_name(var1,varargin)
    for i = varargin
        fprintf('The first name is %s , another is %s',var1,varargin)
    end
```

If the inputs are `name1` `name2` and `name3`, I want the loop to output:

```
    The first name is name1, another is name2 
    The first name is name1, another is name3
```

`fprintf` can't take cell inputs, and changing `varargin` to `varargin{:}` (making it a separated list) is not exactly what I want either because it  doesn't separate out the `varargin` inputs into separate loops.

I also can't use `inputname()` because if the input is an expression rather than a single variable, Matlab returns an empty string `''` when calling input name. Is there some way to still use `inputname()` and add a counter to the loop, or to index the `varargin` inputs and cycle through them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `for i = varargin`, `i` iterates over the elements of `varargin` so you can just change the `varargin` in `fprintf` statement to `i`

```
function = func_name(var1,varargin)
for i = varargin
    fprintf('The first name is %s , another is %s',var1,i)
end
```

By the way, [it is recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab) that you avoid using `i` and `j` as variables in MATLAB.